# JSR 303 implementation gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am implementing custom validation annotation using JSR 303 and I am getting below error. I am following details given at [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95 cannot be cast to com.my.validator.FieldMatch
at com.my.validator.FieldMatchValidator.initialize(FieldMatchValidator.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.initializeConstraint(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:261) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:183) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:122) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:303) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:244) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:617) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you please share the definitions of your constraint annotation and the constraint validator? The constraint annotation may refer to a validator for another annotation type.

Comment: I had a same Exception with different issue.By mistake I had two MyCustomValidator in two different path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have written custom validation annotation then please make sure **@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchValidator.class)** has correct validator class. If validatedBy has different class then you will get ClassCastException. Please refer the similar issue reported at [How to solve cast issue java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy cannot be cast to NotEmpty wich is annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880061/how-to-solve-cast-issue-java-lang-classcastexception-proxy-cannot-be-cast-to-n)

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface FieldMatch
{
}
```